# What must be installed on client machine to run a QT Quick Application?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am developing a desktop application using QT Quick. I have been searching and reading the QT documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-tutorial.html) for creating an installer and how to use `windeployqt.exe` and `binarycreator.exe` to deploy on a windows machine. So far so good , but since I want to target this application for windows XP as well.

I want to know exactly what is required to be installed on the target machine to be able to run my application when using `MinGW` or`MSVC2015` during building, so that I may include them in my installer or make the end user download them. Just like we download .Net Framework , Visual C++ Redistributable or DirectX when installing an application.

Comment: Use `Dependency Walker` do get all dependencies of the binary. Also you must include QtQuick plugins and items you use. In general that what `windeployqt` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `windeployqt` to gather all the Qt official dependencis. Two parameters of `windeployqt` are quite useful:

- `--debug` or `--release`: determine whether your app is in debug state or release state. `windeployqt` will put corresponding version of DLLs to your exe's directory;
- `--qml` and put the directory of your QML files after it. `windeployqt` will search your given directory and put all the QML modules to your exe's directory.

2018-11-05 10:52:34:
It seems the second parameter `--qml` has been changed to `--qmldir`.